# Administrator account gets constant "permission denied" for simple file changes and everything else too

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, uac, wsl2

For 2 or 3 years I have been having to spend way too much time working around this problem my OS has. I just reinstalled Windows 10 (clean, basic default OS) 2 days ago after formatting my whole SSD, hoping I could resolve this, but it is the same. I previously had Windows 10 Pro but just installed Home, thinking that maybe this problem was caused by a security feature in Windows 10 Pro.

I have only 1 user account on my PC, an administrator account. I've tried all the obvious things, in the GUI options (UAC, etc.), tried advanced GUI options like the Advanced Security Settings" page and a few other settings interfaces I found, along with manually taking ownership and full control of every single file via the command line.

All methods say that they work (even command line claimed to have a successful result, but the problem persists. This problem is even present in WSL Ubuntu. If I take control of a file or group of files using `sudo chmod 777`, it seems that the permissions change briefly - there is a short span of time that I am able to make changes to the files but then the problem comes back as soon as I try to do another change.

Is there any way to disable Windows user account based structure? I want to have only 1 account on my PC (besides the automatic system, etc., accounts) and I want my account to be able to do literally anything. This doesn't seem like it should be a complicated task, or a rare request from users. Also it doesn't seem that other people have this problem. What could be wrong? Here's a screenshot of what I see all day.

Access Denied Error, for writing directory in program files:

[image: Screenshot of Access Denied Error, for writing directory in program files]

Answers to questions:

1. How do I know if there was a successful result in trying to give admin privileges? -- each modified file says something like "SUCCESS, PC\MyUserName is now owner of this file".
2. What am I doing that makes this such an annoyance? -- I'm working on an image processing project that uses newly released CUDA (GPU) drivers and needs have a lot of dependencies installed, some that are inside my project's virtual environment and others that have to be installed globally. When I am writing code that accesses these libraries, or installing new libraries or dependencies I get a lot of access denied errors-- sometimes halting an install or image processing task that is partially complete and then needs to restart from the beginning. WSL (Ubuntu) has these errors even for simple things like installing a dependency in my WSL user folder. I also use virtual machines to troubleshoot electronics hardware (I repair computer vision imaging devices) and the virtual machines are separate user accounts. To clarify what I said in my original question so it doesn't seem contradictory: I do currently only have 1 user account on my PC, since I reinstalled. Virtual machines and other tools I use for work create other user accounts, but I haven't installed those yet.
3. Files from old OS causing problems? -- I have 2 partitions on my SSD. I formatted both and got my data files which I keep in the non-OS partition of the SSD, from Dropbox after the reinstall. Do you think they could be causing an issue regardless? Those are just data files, not anything OS or software related.

Comment: Processes within Windows are ran at the lowest permission level possible of the user, this means your Administrator account is both a member of the User and Administrator user group.  This means that unless you use "run as Administrator" on the Visual Studio Code installer, by default, it will run at the lowest permissions.  This behavior cannot be prevented on any version of Windows higher than Windows 7.

Comment: Oh, wow. Is there any way to make my account not classified as a "user" and only as an administrator? Or maybe to have the OS default to running everything as administrator? How does anyone get anything done with this super annoying problem?

Comment: (1) When I installed Windows, I created an administrator account — it forced me to do so.  Then I created an ordinary user account (not in the Administrators group), and I use it all the time.  I actually log in as the administrator account a few times per year; I authenticate as administrator (via UAC) a few times per week.  What are you doing that requires administrator privileges / powers so often that it becomes a nuisance?   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Can you give an example of something that says it works, but doesn’t? If that’s not what you mean in your third paragraph (“All methods say that they work (even command line claimed to have a successful result), but the problem persists.”), please clarify. … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @CristinIrwin - If you put a user into the User user group, they wouldn't be able to escalate the permissions of the process, unless they were able to authenticate as an Administrator.  This means you would still get the permission error.  " How does anyone get anything done with this super annoying problem?" - I escalate the permissions of the process as needed and respond to a 1 second UAC prompt.  It's as simple as having to sudo a command on Linux.  I don't find it annoying in the slighest.

Comment: Sounds like you have more than just the SSD you formatted. Old files created by the previous Windows installation may still have only permissions for your old user account. You can change that by taking ownership of a whole folder and the add your current user account with full access. Note that I am taking about other drives. Please don't do this on your SSD especially not on directories created by the Windows installer.